# SCORM packages in Moodle and case-insensitivity file system

Tags: html, moodle, case-insensitive, scorm

I'm running a custom-developed SCORM package on my local Moodle instance on Windows (which is case-insensitive). I've learned through a couple of researches, that Moodle, by design enforces the case-sensitive file system.

Is there ANY way to override that?

My SCORM package is crashing due to file names inside the HTML. And i can't just fix them cuz i have over 500 modules.

I'll appreciate any help given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure it would be possible to do this just for SCORM, without it affecting how Moodle works with all its files. It might be best to ask on the development forum of moodle.org about this one.

Comment: thanks, am trying that.

Comment: If it's a consistent change needed then you could rename the files - Directory Opus has a large number of ways to do that (including regexp). You could also use something like Notepad++ to do regexp on fixing the links in the files.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i'll use this once i'm sure nothing else will work